# Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT opens different folder in Gallery on different flavours of the app

Tags: android

I have following piece of code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK);
```

When i try to choose image, it opens recents in one flavour of app and in another, it opens screenshots, is there a way I can force to open same directory/folder inside gallery app so behaviour is synced on both flavours.

Comment: Do they run on the same device?

Comment: Yes on same device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to start in the last folder a photo was selected from. I.e. if I open app A and set an image from folder “Foo”, it will open in “Foo” the next time as well. The setting is separate for the app B. If I set an image from folder “Bar” in the app B it will open in “Bar” the next time in the app B, but still “Foo” for the app A.